# How to only show post expiring datetime in 24 hours in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my query

```
$expiring_ads = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post__in'       => get_option('sticky_posts'), 
            'post_type'      => 'post', 
            'posts_per_page' => 5, 
            'no_found_rows'  => true,
            'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'meta_query'     => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'expire_date',
                                        'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                                        'compare' => '>=',
                                        'type' => 'DATETIME'
                                    )
            )
        ));
```

My code show all posts expiring on all dates. How to only show post expiring in 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an [`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) that adds a condition via [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) to check `expire_date` in your database like this:

```
// Create a filtering function to add a WHERE condition to your query like this.
function filter_expire() {
  return " AND expire_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('1 day')) . "'";
}

// Add the filter to the query.
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_expire');

// Run the query.
$expiring_ads = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post__in'       => get_option('sticky_posts'), 
            'post_type'      => 'post', 
            'posts_per_page' => 5, 
            'no_found_rows'  => true,
            'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'meta_query'     => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'expire_date',
                                        'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                                        'compare' => '>=',
                                        'type' => 'DATETIME'
                                    )
            )
        ));
```

**EDIT:** Okay, realized your are using meta post info. So try this:

```
// Run the query.
$expire_window = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('1 day'));
$expiring_ads = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post__in'       => get_option('sticky_posts'), 
            'post_type'      => 'post', 
            'posts_per_page' => 5, 
            'no_found_rows'  => true,
            'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'meta_query'     => array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'expire_date',
                                        'value' => $expire_window,
                                        'compare' => '<='
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'expire_date',
                                        'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                                        'compare' => '>=',
                                        'type' => 'DATETIME'
                                    )
            )
        ));
```

Comment: @JakeGoud: I using postmeta is expire_date, and add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_expire'); not work